# remove both duplicate rows from DataFrame with negative and positive values pands

Tags: python, pandas

DF csv

> This CSV and i am using it as Dataframe

```
colA,colB,colC
ABC,3,token
ABC,50,added    
ABC,-50,deleted
xyz,20,token
pqr,50,added    
pqr,-50,deleted
lmn,50,added
```

> output

```
colA,colB,colC
ABC,3,token
xyz,20,token
lmn,50,added
```

Comment: Can you specify the condition more detail? thank you

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried ? Also from your input and output it's not clear what you are expecting, can you explain the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods based on `abs` would incorrectly remove two positive or two negative values.

I suggest to perform a self-merge using the opposite of colB:

```
# get indices that have a matching positive/negative
idx = (df.reset_index()
         .merge(df, left_on=['colA', 'colB'], right_on=['colA', -df['colB']],
                how='inner')['index']
       )
# [1, 2, 4, 5] (as list)


# drop them
out = df.drop(idx)
```

output:

```
  colA  colB   colC
0  ABC     3  token
3  xyz    20  token
6  lmn    50  added
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to identify all the 'positive and negative' by taking the absolute value. Then drop duplicates based only on `colB` (ignoring the text in `colC`). Don't keep any (`keep=False`) to make sure both are dropped.

```
df.abs().drop_duplicates(subset='colB', keep=False)
```

A small advice, given this is your first post: Please always try to put complete code examples, and make sure you ask a clear question. That makes it easier for other people to understand your problem and reply.
Also, if this answers your question, don't forget to "accept" this answer.

Comment: given your question is not really complete: what happens for example if you have "50, 50, -50"? Do you want to drop all 3 occurrences? Or keep only one of the '50'? Try to complete your question :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure exactly what you mean, this gets the desired output though:

```
df['abs_colB'] = np.abs(df['colB'])
df.drop_duplicates('abs_colB', keep='last').iloc[:, :-1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

|  | colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ABC | 3 | token |
| 1 | xyz | 20 | token |
| 2 | lmn | 50 | added |

Comment: for sure the 'drop' condition is not based on all columns of the `df` and only keeping 'last'... wherd do you think the ordering comes from?

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd.loc[dd.colC.eq("added"),"col1"]=range(0,len(dd.loc[dd.colC.eq("added")]))
    dd.loc[dd.colC.eq("deleted"),"col1"]=range(0,len(dd.loc[dd.colC.eq("deleted")]))
    return dd.assign(colB=dd.colB.abs()).drop_duplicates(subset=["colB","col1"],keep=False).drop("col1",axis=1)

df1.groupby('colA',sort=False).apply(function1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

out：

```
 colA  colB   colC
0  ABC     3  token
1  xyz    20  token
2  lmn    50  added
```